# Pass any struct to a third-party Go library, and have that library able to populate fields in the struct

Tags: go

I have two Go modules. One includes several structs, and here is one example:

```
type FavoriteFood struct {
    Name   string
    Ingredients []string
}
```

The second module has a function similar to this:

```
func Populate(s any) {}
```

I'd like `Populate` to be able to parse the fields available to struct `s`, and then using results from a DB query, marshal those results to fields in `s`, whatever struct `s` may happen to be.

So `FavoriteFood` is passed as `s`, and if a DB query returns the name of a food and several ingredients, I need `Populate` to be able to marshal the DB results to the `FavoriteFood` struct. My issue is that since the struct is defined in a separate module, I don't know how to get `Populate` to save the right values to the right fields in `s`.

Comment: Where does the query come into play? You should be able to use reflection to get the struct's fields and iterate over them. Have you looked into e.g. [gorm](https://gorm.io/index.html)?

Comment: You simply cannot do that. You will either have to pass a pointer or return the struct.